# Error when attempting to include Crypto module: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a register user setup in React JS, installed crypto library from to secure passwords but when I run the program , it gives me an error :

> ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 5:13-30
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\Node
> Tutorial\registerSetup\client\node_modules\jwa'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }

Here is my package.json file :

```
         {
          "name": "registerSetup",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "index.js",
          "scripts": {
          "start": "NODE_ENV= production node server",
          "dev": "nodemon server"
          },
          "keywords": [],
          "author": "",
          "license": "ISC",
          "dependencies": {
          "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
          "cors": "^2.8.5",
          "crypto": "^1.0.1",
          "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
          "dotenv": "^15.0.0",
          "express": "^4.17.2",
          "express-jwt": "^6.1.0",
          "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
          "google-auth-library": "^7.11.0",
          "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
          "loadash": "^1.0.0",
          "lodash": "^4.17.21",
          "mongoose": "^6.1.8",
          "morgan": "^1.10.0",
          "node-fetch": "^3.2.0",
          "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
          "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
          }
         }
```

The package.json for my react folder in registerSetup --> https://pastebin.com/hqBs7J4s

Comment: have you tried putting `var crypto = require("crypto")` or `import crypto from "node:crypto"` in your code?

Comment: yes , check : https://pastebin.com/ZCxF3K7s

Comment: Can you tell use your version of react-scripts in package.json?

Comment: @Magofoco 5.0.0 react scripts version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should go to your node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.json and there write the following code in resolve block

```
fallback: {
           "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
          }
```

Note: crypto-browserify should be installed

Comment: Took me a little while to find it, so for people who want to CTRL+F, as described you can add the code in the following code block:    `resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want`

Answer (score 0):

Crypto is a built-in Node module you don't have to install it. Uninstall "crypto": "^1.0.1" and then try:

```
const crypto = require("crypto")
```

Comment: Same error coming .

Comment: it's only built in before version 5 of react-scripts it seems https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#full-changelog

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downgrade the `react-scripts` in `package.json` version to : `4.0.3`

Comment: It is a temporary solution

Comment: Yes, a temporary one