# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/dell/Desktop/Coding/photography/photo-gallery/node_modules/jwa'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am using React JS and I am building a simple admin login page in MERN stack and using npm packages: jsonwebtoken, react-router-dom, @material-ui/icons.
I am constantly getting a error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 5:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/dell/Desktop/Coding/photography/photo-gallery/node_modules/jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read the error message; it includes a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971125/error-when-attempting-to-include-crypto-module-cant-resolve-crypto?rq=1) question, you need to find your webpack config, add the fallback config, and `npm install crypto-browserify`.